# Dynamic Values in annotations

Tags: annotations

I am writing an annotation based framework for my project. Earlier I was passing static text in annotations and it was working fine.Here is sample code:-

```
public class MyClass{
   @myannotation(name="Hello World")
   private int variable;
   @myannotation(name="Again Hi")
   private int variable1;
}
```

Because of some changes, I need to use a final variables which get its value from a method. I know that annotation can not take dynamic values. So I do a fix for now. I passed a number in name values and when parsing annotation pass this number in a predefined method and it returns that value on basis of that number. Here is code snippet for that:-

```
public class MyClass{
  private static final String finalVar1 = getValue("Hello World");
  private static final String finalVar2 = getValue("Again Hi");
  @myannotation(name="1")
  private int variable;
  @myannotation(name="2")
  private int variable2;

  public String getConvetedValue(String value){
    if(value!=null && value.equals("1")){
        return finalVar1;
    }else if(value!=null && value.equals("2")){
       return finalVar2;
    }
  }
}
```

So in above example getConvertedValue called from annotation parser using reflection and parser pass a number to this method fetched from annotation.

Please suggest me some better solutions for this problem.